# Static files not working with Django, Heroku, and Django Sass Processor

Tags: django, heroku, sass, production, static-files

I can't seem to get static files to work when deploying to Heroku. I get 404s for all css and js files.

Things I'm using:

- Django 2.1.5
- whitenoise 4.1.2
- django-sass-processor 0.7.2
- django-webpack-loader 0.6.0

Here are my settings:

Whitenoise is in the middleware

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
'django.middleware.gzip.GZipMiddleware',
'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',
'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware'
]
```

All of the static file settings:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles/')
STATIC_SOURCE_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    STATIC_SOURCE_ROOT
]

STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'whitenoise.storage.CompressedStaticFilesStorage'

STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
    'sass_processor.finders.CssFinder'
]

# Ensure STATIC_ROOT exists.
os.makedirs(STATIC_ROOT, exist_ok=True)

"""
Django Sass Processor
https://github.com/jrief/django-sass-processor

Template Usage:
{% load sass_tags %}

<link href="{% sass_src 'myapp/css/mystyle.scss' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
"""

SASS_PROCESSOR_INCLUDE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(STATIC_SOURCE_ROOT, 'scss/')
]

SASS_PROCESSOR_ROOT = STATIC_ROOT
SASS_PROCESSOR_ENABLED = False

# Django Webpack Loader
# https://github.com/owais/django-webpack-loader

WEBPACK_LOADER = {
    'DEFAULT': {
        'BUNDLE_DIR_NAME': 'dist/',
        'STATS_FILE': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'webpack-stats-prod.json')
    }
}
```

`DEBUG = False`

When I go to deploy I follow these steps:

1. Run `yarn run build`
   Which builds the js (I'm using React so there is babel and such) and places it into 'static/dist/' - which gets committed to git
2. Deploy to Heroku

   - I have collectstatic disabled on heroku so it doesn't get called automatically on deploy
3. Run on Heroku: `heroku run python manage.py compilescss`

   - Which I believe should compile the scss into css and places the css files next to the scss files in 'static/'
4. Run on Heroku: `heroku run python manage.py collectstatic --ignore=*.scss`

   - Which I believe should copy everything (except .scss) from 'static/' to 'staticfiles/'. This should be all of the compiled css files and the compiled js.

I've played with a lot of settings but nothing seems to work, the css and js get a 404.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please add: 1) generated static file url (in rendered html), 2) full file path on remote drive 3) STATIC_ROOT value

Comment: Committing `static/dist/` is an antipattern. Get Heroku to build your JavaScript for you. There's are _**very** few_ good reasons to commit compiled code.

Comment: Running `manage.py compilecss` and `manage.py collectstatic` interactively, with the goal of building files that live on Heroku's filesystem, won't work as expected. It's ephemeral filesystem will lose those changes whenever your dynos restart (at least daily). You'll have to host those files on a third-party service like Amazon S3 or build them as part of your deployment process so they get included in your application slug. See if [this](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets) helps.

Comment: @Chris How do I get compilescss and collectstatic (with the --ignore=*.scss) to run during deployment? Also how do I get heroku to bundle the js? Is this done in the Procfile?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't used this exact set of tools before, but I think you'll have better luck if you approach things this way:

1. Make sure your application is configured to [run two buildpacks](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/using-multiple-buildpacks-for-an-app). `heroku/nodejs` should run first and `heroku/python` should run second.

   Since you're manually running `yarn` now I suspect that this is already done. `yarn` isn't included in the Python buildpack.
2. Add a [`heroku-postbuild` script](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#customizing-the-build-process) to your `package.json` that runs `yarn build`. This should cause your React code to get built during deployment after your Node.js dependencies have been installed.
3. [Re-enable](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#disabling-collectstatic) Heroku's [automatic `collectstatic`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/django-assets#collectstatic-during-builds) by [running `heroku config:unset DISABLE_COLLECTSTATIC`](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/config-vars#remove-a-config-var). I don't think you actually need to ignore the `.scss` files.

You might also want to take a look at [`django-heroku`](https://github.com/heroku/django-heroku), a Django library from Heroku that helps set up deployment on their platform. It's [officially recommended](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-python#python-deployment-flow) and may well help resolve your HTTP 404 issues.

Comment: Thanks man! That really helped, I got it working. `manage.py compilescss` still needs to be run. I found [heroku-buildpack-django-sass](https://github.com/drpancake/heroku-buildpack-django-sass) which I added as a buildpack after heroku/python. I could probably still leave collectstatic diabled, since the django-sass buildpack runs collectstatic again, but I suppose running it twice doesn't hurt anything.